# Запятая в сложном предложении (тесты Фипи)

Tags: синтаксис

В издании  серии «ФИПИ Я сдам ЕГЭ! Тематический практикум в трёх частях», Часть 2. Москва, просвещение, 2018. Авторы: Цыбулько, Васильевых, Александров, Дощинский, Дякина., есть предложение.

**Девушка села к роялю и дом наполнился нежными звуками.**

Само издание считает, что это сложносочинённое предложение, однако, что там или ноль запятых, или больше одной (формат — «выпишите все предложения с одной запятой» это предложение не входит в список). Это практика к заданию 15 «Знаки препинания в простом осложнённом предложении (с однородными членами) и в сложносочинённом предложении»

Может, у кого-н. есть это издание? Хотелось бы точно прочитать задание, чтобы узнать,почему, по их мнению, запятая не должна стоять. Издания у меня нет,это  вопрос с другого сайта).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так: **Девушка села к роялю — и дом наполнился нежными звуками.**

Тире как неосновной знак при неожиданном присоединении.

Comment: Гениальная догадка про тире! Но здесь скорее результат, чем неожиданное присоединение (§ 171. Тире ставится между предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если второе предложение заключает в себе результат или вывод из того, о чем говорится в первом, например: 
Хвалы приманчивы – как их не пожелать? 
Крылов
Солнце взошло – начинается день. 
Некрасов)

Comment: В том-то и дело, что про тире там ничего не говорится.

Comment: Всем ясно: или запятая, или тире. Третьего не дано.

Comment: Tо что запятая должна быть - это ясно. Мне было интересно, как они мотивируют отсутствие запятой.

Comment: Сегодня автор вопроса предоставил скан задания. Задание см. в вопросе. Раз  в списке нет этого номера, значит, скорее всего, по их мнению, здесь нужно тире.

Answer (score 2):

> В издании серии «ФИПИ Я сдам ЕГЭ! Тематический практикум в трёх
>   частях», Часть 2. Москва, просвещение, 2018. Авторы: Цыбулько,
>   Васильевых, Александров, Дощинский, Дякина., есть предложение.
>
> **Девушка села к роялю и дом наполнился нежными звуками.**

Посмотрел это издание в книжном м-не. По-моему, какого-либо глубинного смысла в отсутствии предложения 13 в ответах к практикуму искать не стоит. Похоже на обыкновенный ляп.

Конечно, можно говорить о возможности постановки тире. Но если автор захочет, может поставить и запятую. Паустовский в похожем предложении поставил именно запятую:

***Вечером она зажгла свечи, села к роялю, и дом наполнился звоном.***

С запятой это предложение Паустовского присутствует и в ряде учебных пособий по русскому языку.

Comment: Да, Вы правы: скорее ляп.